Scraping cookies from Websites with headless browsers and php
I have tried to write a program in php that scrapes the cookies from websites while connecting with curl and using the $_COOKIE functionality.
Turns out i can only read php cookies like this but i also want to get the JavaScript cookies.
Because of that i tried a different approach with python and selenium (browser automation tool for webscraping) which worked well, but i want a php solution.
what i now search for is a method that scrapes cookies the same way i can do with python and selenium.
below is my php script that i first used which only works for php cookies.
$ch = curl_init('https://www.google.com/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101026 Firefox/3.6.12');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

preg_match_all('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi', $result, $matches);
$cookies = array();
foreach($matches[1] as $item) {
    parse_str($item, $cookie);
    $cookies = array_merge($cookies, $cookie);
}
var_dump($cookies);


A Curl request will get you cookies set by the server only. If any of the cookies you're looking for are controlled by JavaScript, you won't see them - you just get the initial info provided by the server, just as a browser would. PHP/curl can't execute JavaScript so anything relying on JavaScript won't be available. To get JS cookies you'll want to run a browser-like environment. There are headless browsers available for PHP, including clients for Selenium I believe (although I haven't used them personally)

I believe there is a PHP port of Selenium, but I wouldn't recommend it.  Can you run Java on your server?

you both were right, there is a PHP port for Selenium which worked perfectly for my needs. thanks to both.

As stated above, Curl will only get you cookies that the server sets but not JavaScript cookies (or server cookies that are guarded). The solution is to run a headless browsers like selenium.
i found a great tutorial to set everything up:
https://www.zenrows.com/blog/selenium-php#install-selenium-in-php
